# How long does a good AES encryption take?

Tags: encryption, aes, stream-cipher

I am encrypting large file sizes (>1GB) using AES encryption with a key size of **256** and over a **1000** hash iterations. To make the program memory efficient I'm reading the file from the stream, chunk by chunk (of specific buffer lengths) and encrypting them.

However, to encrypt a file of roughly **1GB** it just takes me **~6 secs** on a Mac with 16GB memory and **2.2 GHz i7 processor**. Is it normal that it takes **only** this much time? Or should I be concerned? does it usually take longer? Or (as I read) is it given AES's quality to be fast?

Any help in understanding the scenario will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: My computer processes AES-128 at 3GB/s

Comment: @RichieFrame - So it's not an abnormal behaviour? It's an acceptable thing is it?

Comment: AES itself is very fast. Your 'over a 1000 hash iterations' suggests you are using a _Password-Based_ encryption scheme, which is different from plain AES. The Password-Based Key Derivation _step_ should be relatively slow; that's what the iteration count is for, although in the last two decades there are now PBKD schemes that are much safer than a plain iterated hash.

Comment: **CAUTION: most likely 1000 hash iterations is not enough.** These likely are for [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching), perhaps PBKDF2 or similar, or iterating a standard hash. Since you find that 6 seconds is acceptable, you can probably spend 1 second at key stretching, and with proper implementation we are talking orders of magnitude more that 1000 hash iterations!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this answer [Different ways/algorithms for implementing AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/different-ways-algorithms-for-implementing-aes/44675#44675) you can see that AES is already pretty fast. By using the hardware instruction you can even get down to $\sim1.3$ cycles/byte[[1]](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/10TB24_Breakthrough_AES_Performance_with_Intel_AES_New_Instructions.final.secure.pdf).

$1 GB = 2^{30} B \approx 10^9 B$

Your CPU is working at $2.2$ GHz, in other word $2.2 \times 10^9$ cycles per second. To encrypt $1 GB$ you need $1.3 \times 2^{30}$ cycles. In other word, it would take $\frac{1.3 \times 2^{30}}{2.2 \times 10^9} = 0.634$ seconds. So clearly AES is super fast.

**read more:**

- [[1] Breakthrough AES Performance with Intel® AES New Instructions](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/10TB24_Breakthrough_AES_Performance_with_Intel_AES_New_Instructions.final.secure.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Very Much. This solves my dilemma and I will mark it as correct since it also directs me to sources I can further understand this.